# visual assist x dark color theme

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-assist

I have installed visual assist X, I use visual studio for my C++ development. However, I am not sure how can I enable the dark theme color scheme as mentioned here http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/color.asp?

Answer (score 7):

According to the documentation at the link, if you have a dark background and press the "use defaults" button, the colors will default to ones appropriate for a dark scheme:

> The scheme selected upon installation or when pressing Use Defaults in
>   the VA Options Dialog depends on your current IDE color scheme.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for solarized dark :(

Answer (score 1):

Allegedly, you can [set a value in the registry](https://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W494) to fix it:

> You can coax Visual Assist into making its decisions differently, e.g. into assuming your theme is similar to the Dark theme, by setting the following registry DWORD value:
>
> HKCU\Software\Whole Tomato\Visual Assist X\\VsThemeColorBehavior

Set to 2 to assume unknown themes are Dark.

However, I couldn't find it doesn't work for my version of Visual Assist (requires 2023, but doesn't work on 2258). Also, the registry value is reset to 0 when I open VAssist Options.

The only theme I can get it to use dark colours for is "Dark" which uses a light editor (!?).